# How to connect elasticache and dynamoDb from aws-lambda without using NAT Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

I need to connect dynamoDb and elasticache from aws-lambda (otherthan using NAT Gateway).

ElastiCache provides essential caching methods along with help in making the Lambda state-ful. The concern is that for Lambda to work nice with DynamoDB it should be set to NoVPC.

If we have to use ElastiCache, Lambda and both have to be in the same VPC.TO use Both ElastiCache and DynamoDB together is quite a challenge specially with Lambda. Given the VPC challenges.Do you have any suggestions to make this easier?

Comment: have you able to access and work with memcache without VPC  in  Lambda?

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

A Lambda function would have to have VPC access to connect to ElastiCache, and it would have to have access to resources outside the VPC to access DynamoDB so it would require a NAT gateway. There is no way to provide access to both of those services to a single Lambda function without enabling VPC access and setting up a NAT gateway.

If you just need a Redis server and aren't required specifically to use ElasiCache, then you could use a [RedisLabs](https://redislabs.com/) instance which wouldn't require you to enable VPC access on your Lambda function.

Comment: would NAT gateway be a single point of failure for the entire ecosystem?

Comment: Not if you use Managed NAT Gateway. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-nat-network-address-translation-gateway-for-aws/ *"The gateway has built-in redundancy for high availability."*

Answer (score 0):

There is now a relatively easy solution for DynamoDb access from a VPC: VPC Endpoints.

"Previously, if you wanted your EC2 (elroy: or lambda)  instances in your VPC to be able to access DynamoDB, you had two options. You could use an Internet Gateway (with a NAT Gateway or assigning your instances public IPs) or you could route all of your traffic to your local infrastructure via VPN or AWS Direct Connect and then back to DynamoDB."

"A VPC endpoint for DynamoDB enables Amazon EC2 instances in your VPC to use their private IP addresses to access DynamoDB with no exposure to the public Internet...Your EC2 instances do not require public IP addresses, and you do not need an Internet gateway, a NAT device, or a virtual private gateway in your VPC. You use endpoint policies to control access to DynamoDB. Traffic between your VPC and the AWS service does not leave the Amazon network. "

The above quotes come from the links below.  Note the the references to "EC2 instances" apply to lambda contexts as well.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoints-for-dynamodb/

and

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html